# Unable to get button value into function

Tags: javascript, html

Working on TOD calculator project.
While I likely have other potential errors in my code, I am only seeking to understand getting the button number/value into the function.
I think I need to get the button value assigned so that the
xyz function can process it.  Is it even necessary to add the value attribute to a CSS button in this instance?

```
     <div class="row4">
        <button class="btn" value="7">7</button>
        <button class="btn" value="8">8</button>
        <button class="btn" value="9">9</button>
        <button class="btn" value="*">*</button>
      </div>
```

```
let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i += 1) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", xyz);

 function xyz(x) {
    let nbr1 = "0";
    let operator = "";
    let nbr2 = "0";
    const sum = maths(nbr1, operator, nbr2);
    if (x == "=") button.value = sum;
    if (x == "+" || "-" || "*" || "/") x = operator;
    if (operator == null) x = nbr1;
    else x = nbr2;
    console.log(nbr1, operator, nbr2);
  }
}
```

`document.getElementsByClassName("btn").value` causes an

> uncaught typeError: buttons is undefined

Without `.values` the function runs without errors, but none
of the values get assigned.

I have tried:

- `getAttributes(‘value’)` and get: "not a function" typeError.
- a number of different iterations in the (xyz) of lines such as: x, buttons, buttons.value etc.

Comment: The key issue is that `x` here: `function xyz(x) {` is the _click event_ not the value. To get at the value you'd want something like `function xyz(event)` and then `event.target.value`. But ALSO your function should be _outside_ of the loop.

Comment: Did you debug at all? `console.log(x)`

Comment: @expascarello I've used many console.log iterations to get to where I am. While its been very helpful its not getting past my current position.

Comment: @Andy it seems to me that I need to put the loop inside the function. Is my logic on track?

Comment: I'd misread the error you posted so will delete my answer (I thought the element <collection> was undefined - which usually means the code executed before the element was rendered). Your event listener works fine but as @Andy points out, it currently declared the same function on every loop, move it outside.

Comment: @Andy yes its a function to process the data once I can get it to appear in xyz,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are redefining the function in every iteration of the loop (not necessary and not optimal). Just define the function before you start the loop.
The event handler will be passed the event object as the parameter. The `event.target` points to the actual clicked-on element which may be a child of the button, while `event.currentTarget` will be the element the handler was assigned to (the button itself).
If you only have the button value nested inside it then you can use `event.currentTarget.innerText` instead of `event.currentTarget.value` to get the value attribute.

```js
let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

function xyz(event) {
  const btnVal = event.currentTarget.innerText
  console.log(btnVal);
}
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i += 1) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", xyz);
}
```

```html
<div class="row4">
  <button class="btn">7</button>
  <button class="btn">8</button>
  <button class="btn">9</button>
  <button class="btn">*</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Might as well use `.value` since it exists on the button.